# Can I group objects on layers with different opacities in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a map visualizing some data. I have data from different years on different layers, and I am using different opacities to show the difference in time. Each layer has a lot of different objects on it, so I am changing the opacity of the layer rather than each individual object.

Now that I'm done with the map and am working on a different part of the same document, I want to group or link all the map layers together so I don't accidentally move one of them relative to the others, since it would be really difficult to get it back in the right alignment. However, when I try to group the objects, they are all moved to the same layer and given the same opacity. Is there any way to group objects without moving them to the same layer? Or to link layers together so they can't be moved relative to each other?

(I know I can lock each layer individually, but ideally I would like to be able to move the whole group as a single object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto your Layers -panel. Make a new layer "Map items" and drag all your ready layers into it. Lock layer "Map items". Unlock it if you want to move map items, select layer "Map items" in the layers panel and drag one object, the others follow.

[image]

Every year-layer here has only one rectangle.